# Configure Play 2.1 to fetch a privately hosted artefact from local Nexus

Tags: playframework, sbt, playframework-2.1, nexus

My company has several Maven-based projects which we publish to our locally hosted, private Nexus repository.

We also have a Play 2.1 based application which needs to use several of these artefacts.

How can I configure SBT so that it queries our local Nexus repository?  Proxying all other Ivy and Maven Central dependencies through Nexus is not required, but considered a plus.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following `Build.scala` retrieves private artefacts from the Nexus repository, retrieves other manually enrolled artefacts from the Nexus repository, and proxies Maven Central via Nexus:

```
import sbt._
import Keys._
import play.Project._

object ApplicationBuild extends Build 
{
  val appName         = "foo"
  val appVersion      = "0.0.1-SNAPSHOT"

  val appDependencies = Seq(
    javaCore,
    "com.private" % "foo" % "1.0.0"
  )

  val main = play.Project(appName, appVersion, appDependencies).settings(
    externalResolvers <<= resolvers map { rs => Resolver.withDefaultResolvers(rs, mavenCentral = false)},
    resolvers += "Nexus Public Proxy" at "http://private.com/nexus/content/groups/public/",
    resolvers += "Nexus 3rd party" at "http://private.com/nexus/content/repositories/thirdparty/",
    resolvers += "Nexus Private Releases" at "http://private.com/nexus/content/repositories/releases/"
  )
}
```

The Typesafe Ivy dependencies are still downloaded directly, as I couldn't get Nexus to proxy them successfully.

Comment: You do not have to add 3rd party and private releases since they are (at least by default) already exposed int he public group.

Comment: @ManfredMoser: noted with thanks.  I'll leave this answer the way it is since it at least shows configuring multiple other resolvers - but you're right when you say Nexus could be configured to present all those artefacts via one group.